# Bullets not showing in JTextPane

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jeditorpane

I am developing an editor in Java in which I want to include bullets of different types.  I am using `HtmlEditorKit`. I wanted to add a style sheet but it is not working, I wanted to know if following Pseudo element is  supported in Java, if it is supported can you please guide me where I am going wrong?

```
styleSheet.addRule("ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0px 20px;}");
styleSheet.addRule("li:before{content: \"&#10020\";}");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java HTML rendering engine only supports a (very) limited amount of CSS.

Comment: isnt there a way out.

Comment: If you consider 'program it yourself' to be 'way out' then yes.